# Python sys.argv to remove single quotes (')

Tags: python-3.8, sys

I need to pass an argument to trial_id as follow: `trial_id [123, 412, 351, 236]`
For some reason, after argument is passed, single quotes are added and breaks my code.

Python command is `python3 pull_t3.py 123,412,351,236`

```
trial_ids = [sys.argv[1]]
print("trial_id", trial_ids)
```

prints

```
trial_id ['123,412,351,236']
```

How can I remove single quotes (')? I would prefer the python sys argument does not change. Rater something in the code.

Comment: `trial_ids = sys.arg[v]`.  Wrapping in extra [] makes a list with single string.  If you want a string don't do that.  The quotes aren't part of the string.  They are just a display representation of a string when in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the file with the arguments like the way you just did, you have only passed in one argument. A single string. And that's what the output gives back to you.

```
python3 pull_t3.py 123,412,351,236
```

So, if you want to pass in multiple arguments, you separate each argument with a whitespace, and not a comma. Like so:

```
python3 pull_t3.py 123 412 351 236
```

Now, the correction you'll have to make in your script for that is this:
Now that you're passing in multiple arguments, they'll be accessible at argv[1], argv[2]... etc. So you can just slice the list like so:

```
trial_ids = sys.argv[1:]
```

That takes every argument you run the file with.

Your output will now look something like this:

```
trial_id ['123', '412', '351', '236']
```

You now have each argument as a separate **String**. You can then easily convert all elements in the list to **ints** with a list comprehension like this:

```
trial_ids = [int(i) for i in trial_ids]
```

Hope that resolves your issue